# Creating a Dynamic Ingress Rule for Terraform (AWS) - Reading from File

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have banged my head against the wall for several days now with this, and I am at my wits-end.
The problem *sounds* simple - create a dynamic ingress rule for terraform by reading ports from a file.
I'm having difficulty having a for_each rule actually apply consistently here; What am I overlooking?

The files that are being read from, something1.txt and something2.txt can handle a single port number fine - but any newline added by 'echo "22" >> something1.txt' will cause the following error:

> │ When expanding the plan for aws_security_group.YouWish to include new values learned so far during apply, provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
> │ produced an invalid new value for .ingress: length changed from 3 to 4.
> │
> │ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker.

```
resource "null_resource" "create_files" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "bash ${path.module}/portdecoder.sh" # This is a command querying local config files about what ports they need open and which they need pointed somewhere else, often in the form of cat file | grep '[0-9]+' >> something1.txt
      }
}

data "local_file" "something1" {
  filename = "${path.module}/something1.txt"
  depends_on = [null_resource.create_files]
}

data "local_file" "something2" {
  filename = "${path.module}/something2.txt"
  depends_on = [null_resource.create_files]
}

locals {
  ingress_ts_ports = split("\n", trimspace(data.local_file.something1.content))
  ingress_rd_ports = split("\n", trimspace(data.local_file.something2.content))
}

resource "aws_security_group" "YouWish" {
    name = "YouWish"
    description = "YOUWISH Security Group - Autogen"
    vpc_id = "vpc-***************"
    dynamic "ingress" { # ingress something1
        for_each = local.ingress_ts_ports
        content {
            from_port   = tonumber(ingress.value)
            to_port     = tonumber(ingress.value)
            protocol    = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks = ["*.*.*.*/**"] # This is obfuscated, not actual value 
        }
    }
    dynamic "ingress" { # ingress rd
        for_each = local.ingress_rd_ports
        content {
            from_port   = tonumber(ingress.value)
            to_port     = tonumber(ingress.value)
            protocol    = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks = ["*.*.*.*/**"] # This is obfuscated, not actual value 
        }
    }
}
```

The 'portdecoder'

```bash
base64 -d someconfigfile | grep NGINX_PORT | grep -oE '[0-9]+' >> something1.txt
# Below will be some 'default' ports to run over that need to be pointed somewhere else
echo "80" >> something2.txt
echo "443" >> something2.txt
# ideally wanted to use echo "80\n443\n8080\n" >> something2.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure you can call the dynamic block with the same name. Have you tried with dynamic "ingress_1" and dynamic "ingress_2" ?

Comment: `ingress` is a keyword, it cannot be anything else.

Comment: Ah yes...you are right. By the way, if the port is the only thing that change, then a quick solution would be to merge rd and ts variables and loop trough it. The other option, as it is already answered is to use separate Terraform ingress and egress resource, which is something I always tend to use.

Comment: rd and ts variables cannot be merged, as they must have different values assigned in other areas - such as non-matching CIDR blocks.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is using a separate [aws_security_group_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) resource. That way you can have more control over what gets added and you don't need to use `dynamic` and `ingress` within the security group resource. In short, I would switch to using the following:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "YouWish" {
    name = "YouWish"
    description = "YOUWISH Security Group - Autogen"
    vpc_id = "vpc-***************"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ts_ports" {
  for_each          = toset(local.ingress_ts_ports)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = tonumber(each.value)
  to_port           = tonumber(each.value)
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["*.*.*.*/**"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.YouWish.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rd_ports" {
  for_each          = toset(local.ingress_rd_ports)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = tonumber(each.value)
  to_port           = tonumber(each.value)
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["*.*.*.*/**"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.YouWish.id
}
```

My best guess is that terraform gets tripped up by the fact you have two dynamic blocks of the same type, so this should solve the issue you are facing. Also, if you want to be even more precise, you could consider using [`aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_security_group_ingress_rule) resource.

Comment: I'm getting following error: The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of string.
How would I transform the source so that I can avoid this?

Comment: What does the file look like?